# Why iterators are not a solution for CuncurentModificationException?

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, listiterator

I wanted to avoid syncing so I tried to use iterators. The only place where I modify array looks as follows:

```
    if (lastSegment.trackpoints.size() > maxPoints)
    {
        ListIterator<TrackPoint> points = lastSegment.trackpoints.listIterator();
        points.next();
        points.remove();
    }
    ListIterator<TrackPoint> points = lastSegment.trackpoints.listIterator(lastSegment.trackpoints.size());
    points.add(lastTrackPoint);
```

And array traversal looks as follows:

```
    for (Iterator<Track.TrackSegment> segments = track.getSegments().iterator(); segments.hasNext();)
    {
        Track.TrackSegment segment = segments.next();
        for (Iterator<Track.TrackPoint> points = segment.getPoints().iterator(); points.hasNext();)
        {
            Track.TrackPoint tp = points.next();
            //                    ^^^ HERE I GET ConcurentModificationException
            //                    =============================================
            ...
        }
    }
```

So, what's wrong with iterators? Second level arrays are huge, so I do not want to copy them nor I want to rely on synchronization outside of my `Track` class.

Comment: I don't understand... staahp. What are you even doing? What are you syncing, what does your Track-class look like.. and Why do you even think that Iterators magically solve multithreading issues??

Comment: So, they don't? Then I'm mislead.

Comment: Note that `ConcurrentModificationException` does *not necessarily have anything* to do with multthreading/concurrency. You can very easily trigger this exception in single-threaded code. Does your `for` loop modify `segment.getPoints()` (directly or indirectly, via some other method)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html

> For example, it is not generally permissible for one thread to modify a Collection while another thread is iterating over it. In general, the results of the iteration are undefined under these circumstances. Some Iterator implementations (**including those of all the general purpose collection implementations provided by the JRE**) may choose to throw this exception if this behavior is detected.

You will need to implement some sort of synchronization yourself to avoid the exception. You may consider using `Collections.synchronizedList` and only operating on the list through that view.